# Is it not possible to stack groupboxs?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a simple lunch ordering system. I'm using 5 group boxes with 4 radio buttons in each to create a menu for vendor that serves the school. I have the code to make the menu that corresponds with the day of the week visible while hiding all other menus. I tried to stack the menus on top of each other for simple placement while inputting information and the groupboxs don't show when the day is clicked. Whenever they are not stacked, they work just fine. Is this a glitch or something I just don't know?

The default value of the menus(groupboxs) are set to visible=false. When set to true it still does the same thing.

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged

    If DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek.ToString = WeekdayName(2) Then
        chaisGB.Visible = True
        mcalistersTuesGB.Visible = False
        mcalistersWedGB.Visible = False
        chickfilaGB.Visible = False
        hungryHowieGB.Visible = False
    ElseIf DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek.ToString = WeekdayName(3) Then
        mcalistersTuesGB.Visible = True
        chaisGB.Visible = False
        mcalistersWedGB.Visible = False
        chickfilaGB.Visible = False
        hungryHowieGB.Visible = False
    ElseIf DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek.ToString = WeekdayName(4) Then
        mcalistersWedGB.Visible = True
        chaisGB.Visible = False
        mcalistersTuesGB.Visible = False
        chickfilaGB.Visible = False
        hungryHowieGB.Visible = False
    ElseIf DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek.ToString = WeekdayName(5) Then
        chickfilaGB.Visible = True
        chaisGB.Visible = False
        mcalistersTuesGB.Visible = False
        mcalistersWedGB.Visible = False
        hungryHowieGB.Visible = False
    ElseIf DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek.ToString = WeekdayName(6) Then
        hungryHowieGB.Visible = True
        chaisGB.Visible = False
        mcalistersTuesGB.Visible = False
        mcalistersWedGB.Visible = False
        chickfilaGB.Visible = False

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of down voting, why not tell me why this is a bad question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are actually dragging one `GroupBox` into another in the designer.  To place a number of controls in the same place with the same parent, try this.  Drag all the controls onto the desired parent, e.g. the form itself, in any old position.  Now, select all the controls by using Shift+Drag or Ctrl+Click.  Open the Properties window and then set the `Size` and `Location` properties manually.  You'll then find that all the controls are "stacked" on top of each other.

You can also use the Document Outline window to move controls into and out of parent containers and change the z-order of controls in the same container.

You can also simplify that code considerably.  Always remember the DRY principle: don't repeat yourself. E.g.

```
Dim selectedGroupBox As GroupBox

Select Case DateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek
    Case DayOfWeek.Monday
        selectedGroupBox = chaisGB
    Case DayOfWeek.Tuesday
        selectedGroupBox = mcalistersTuesGB
    Case DayOfWeek.Wednesday
        selectedGroupBox = mcalistersWedGB
    Case DayOfWeek.Thursday
        selectedGroupBox = chickfilaGB
    Case DayOfWeek.Friday
        selectedGroupBox = hungryHowieGB
End Select

Dim allGroupBoxes = {chaisGB, mcalistersTuesGB, mcalistersWedGB, chickfilaGB, hungryHowieGB}

Array.ForEach(allGroupBoxes, Sub(gb) gb.Visible = (gb Is selectedGroupBox))
```

Comment: I think you might have been right about the dragging the boxes together. I set the location property to the same thing for each groupbox and used your simplified code. Everything works just fine accordingly. Thanks for you attention and help on the matter.